# How to implement token authentication and authorization with vuejs/vuex and ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, vuejs2, jwt, vuex

I have implemented the frontend of a web app in vuejs and the backend using asp.net web api. Users are authenticated against a LDAP server. I already implemented the login part and I received the token in the header together with an expiry date but i dont know how to proceed from there. Guides that i have been reading are on OAuth, Okta and so on. How do i retrieve the token and expiry date from the header and save the user information using vuex and keep sessions?

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Login(string quad, string password)
        {
            if(Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var basicAuthenticationIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
                if(basicAuthenticationIdentity != null)
                {
                    var username = basicAuthenticationIdentity.Name;
                    return GetAuthToken(username);
                }
                return null;

            }
            return null;
        }


    private HttpResponseMessage GetAuthToken(string quad)
    {
        var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        DateTime issuedOn = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime expiredOn = issuedOn.AddMinutes(30);
        var tokendomain = new TOKEN
        {
            QUAD = quad,
            ISSUED_ON = issuedOn,
            EXPIRES_ON = expiredOn,
            AUTHTOKEN = token
        };
        var db = new KronosDB("public");
        db.Tokens.Add(tokendomain);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Authorized");
        response.Headers.Add("Token", tokendomain.AUTHTOKEN);
        response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", tokendomain.EXPIRES_ON.ToString());
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");
        return response;
    }
```

I am close in implementing the authentication but still have an issue in the App.vue. Here is the code:

```
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters({ currentUser: 'currentUser' })
    },
    created () {
      this.checkCurrentLogin()
    },
    updated () {
      this.checkCurrentLogin()
    },
    methods: {
      checkCurrentLogin () {
        if (!this.currentUser && this.$route.path !== '/login') {
          // this.$router.push('/?redirect=' + this.$route.path)
          this.$router.push('/login')
        }
      }
    },
```

The vuex index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules:{
    auth
  },
})
```

the auth

```
import User from '../model/User'
import * as MutationTypes from './mutation_types'
const state = {
  user: User.from(localStorage.token)
}

const mutations = {
  [MutationTypes.LOGIN] (state) {
    state.user = User.from(localStorage.token)
  },
  [MutationTypes.LOGOUT] (state) {
    state.user = null
  }
}
const getters = {
  currentUser (state) {
    return state.user
  }
}

const actions = {
  login ({ commit }) {
    commit(MutationTypes.LOGIN)
  },

  logout ({ commit }) {
    commit(MutationTypes.LOGOUT)
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions
}
```

The mutation_types

export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN'
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT'

When i remove the computed properties 'updated' from the App.vue, it works and it does not when i add the 'updated' computed properties. Also the vuex bindings "currentUser" remains null.

Comment: I implemented this feature successfully.. Answer will be posted later.

Answer (score 0):

For making ajax calls from vue app you can make use axios vue library. This blog [handling ajax request](https://medium.com/techtrument/handling-ajax-request-in-vue-applications-using-axios-1d26c47fab0) will help to get start with that.

Once you receive the token and expiry as ajax response, save the token and expiry in localStorage or cookies or sessionStorage based on your preference.

And to restrict page access, if you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) library, in [beforeEach](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) callback check for the token expiry and redirect to login page if expired. To make authenticated api call attach the token in header before sending requests to server.

Comment: how are you saving the data in localstorage in ajax response? what code is in your user and mutation_types file?